# Finding min value of an array using SIMD

Tags: c#, .net, simd

I have the following code to find the minimum `sbyte` value in an array. It is using `System.Runtime.Intrinsics` to perform a SIMD min on chunks of the array, and then loops over the resulting vector to find the true minimum.

```
public static sbyte Min( sbyte[] array )
{
  if( array.Length <= 0 )
    return 0;

  var length = array.Length;
  var stepSize = Vector128<sbyte>.Count;

  fixed ( sbyte* pStep = &array[ 0 ] )
  {
    var i = stepSize;
    var minVector = Avx.LoadVector128( pStep );
    for( ; i <= length - stepSize; i += stepSize )
      minVector = Avx.Min( minVector, Avx.LoadVector128( pStep + i ) );

    var _ = stackalloc sbyte[ stepSize ];
    Avx.Store( _, minVector );

    // Find min of minVector
    var min = sbyte.MaxValue;
    for( var j = 0; j < stepSize; j++ )
      if( min > _[ j ] )
        min = _[ j ];

    // Evaluate remaining elements
    if( i < length )
      while( i < length )
      {
        if( min > pStep[ i ] )
          min = pStep[ i ];
        i++;
      }

    return min;
  }
}
```

I feel like this is a slightly excessive amount of code, but seeing how this function is meant to handle arrays with lengths that can't be equally partitioned into a 128-bit register, I'm not sure if there's any cleaner way to do this.

I do intend to implement this method for all supported primitive types, but it seems like most of the code will just be duplicated.

Comment: `var _` - what an _unconventional_ variable name is this? o_O I'm also giving you a -1 for that because it's just impolite to use names like this one and expect people to understand your code.

Comment: While I don't share t3ch0t's sentiment completely, `_` is a terrible variable name, and is now used as a [discard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards), which may create confusion.

Answer (score 3):

### Correctness

```
  if( array.Length <= 0 )
    return 0;
```

This piece of code is suspicious. Maybe you should return `sbyte.MaxValue`, maybe `null`, or maybe throw `ArgumentException`. (I can imagine that there were a `Max` method, both, together is used to find the range of values, then maybe `0` is a valid return value.) This is one of the rare times I'd appreciate a comment to explain such extrinsic information.

### Useless Code

```
 if( i < length )
      while( i < length )
```

Lose the `if`.

### Excessive code

When you are operating on fixed size chunks, 
 - pad the input with some appropriate value (`sbyte.MaxValue`)
 - handle the last fixed size chunk of the input separately.

The last suggestion should read something like this, (which means I don't even guarantee that it will compile):

```
if (length < stepSize)
    throw new ArgumentException($"this method cannot be used for arrays shorter than {stepSize}") 

Vector128<sbyte> minVector;
SetAllVector128(minVector, sbyte.MaxValue);
for (var i = 0; i < length - stepSize; i += stepSize)
    minVector = Avx.Min(minVector, Avx.LoadVector128(pStep + i));

minVector = Avx.Min(minVector, Avx.LoadVector128(pStep + length - stepSize));
```

Then you can use the last loop altogether;

Comment: +1; I don't think there is any need to do the 'padding'; you can just load the first/final vector before the loop, and it will be fine. I think you can put a +1 in the loop condition so that it doesn't run the final block twice if `length % stepSize == 0`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others it's a problem when the size of the input array is lesser than `Vector128<sbyte>.Count`. You can handle it by taking the min of the two as `stepSize`:

```
int stepSize = Math.Min(Vector128<sbyte>.Count, array.Length);
```

This is safe because the first for-loop will only run if `stepSize > vector size` and the first `while-loop` will only iterate the actual number of elements in `array`.

---

Alternatively you can make some proper input checks like:

```
  if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
  if (array.Length == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Input must contains data.");

  if (array.Length < Vector128<sbyte>.Count)
    return array.Min();
```

You should do the first two checks anyway...

Comment: You still need to explicitly avoid any calls to `LoadVector128` (e.g. the first in the OP, the last in abuzittin gillifirca's answer). I'm assuming that it could seg-fault (at some level), but even if it doesn't blow up it is not polite to read memory you can't control. I also think an explicit check (like abuzittin gillifirca's, though it needn't throw) would be better because it makes the intention clear, whereas setting up loops so that they implicitly don't run is a bit cryptic.

Comment: @VisualMelon: I don't see your point. The minimum stepSize prevents effectively reading uncontrolled memory.

Comment: I mean - for example in the OP's code - that even if the `for` loop cycles, that `var minVector = Avx.LoadVector128( pStep );` will. It's not impossible I'm completely confused.

Comment: @VisualMelon: OK, but if `array.Length < Vector128<sbyte>.Count`, the result is a vector padded with `0´ (defaults). Is seems safe to use by me :-)

Comment: I don't know, it just feels wrong to me ;) It necessarily involves reading beyond the length of the array, and you can't make assumptions about whether you own that memory or not (maybe the structure of the HEAP in the CLR means it's safe enough, but that's an implementation detail). Your second piece of code would make me much happier indeed!